# Random error when piping twice http request

Tags: node.js, request, pipe, fs

I have this code:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(_filename, _saveFile);
var request = http.request(options);
var decrypt = Crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);

var _saveFile = function(response) {
  res.pipe(decrypt).pipe(file);
  res.on("end", function() {
    file.close();
  });
};

file.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log("Error while writing file", err);
});
```

It works ok. But randomly I'm receiving this error:

```
{ [Error: EBADF, write] errno: 9, code: 'EBADF' }
```

I read this is because the file is being written after it was closed. So, the question I have is: Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to do `decrypt.on("end")`instead of `res.on("end")`?

**MORE INFORMATION**

In the same res.on("end") I have a q.defer().resolve call, because this method is downloading several .ts files and then I need to turn them into a MP4.

As @mscdex said, there is no need to close the file, however, if the promise is resolved before the file has been actually finished then, I may be working with a corrupted file. Like this:

1. Download 1.ts
2. Download 2.ts
3. Download 3.ts

   - Here all the promises are saved in a an array and then I use `q.spread` to wait for all of them
4. File 1.ts writted
5. File 1.ts resolve promise
6. File 2.ts writted
7. File 2.ts resolve promise
8. File 3.ts resolve promise
9. `q.spread` knows all the promises were resolved so it starts working with the .ts files
10. File 3.ts writted

    - From this point on, I'll be working with a wrong/incomplete file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly call `file.close()` since the file stream will be closed automatically when upstream ends.

If you need to wait until the file is completely written, listen for the `finish` event on `file`:

```
file.on('finish', function() {
  // resolve promise or do whatever
});
```

Comment: In that ```file.on("end")``` I have also a promise resolving. Check the update to have more info on what I'm doing.

Comment: Writable streams (e.g. `file`) do not emit `end`, they emit `finish` when there is no more writing and all data has been flushed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant res.on("end");

Comment: Resolve your promises inside a `finish` event handler, since the response stream's `end` event could easily fire before the file stream finishes writing to disk.